# Is it possible to apply a function to one column when reading a data file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Is there a way to apply directly a Series operation (buid in function or custom) when building a dataframe from a file (in a pythonic way)?

I would like to change the following:

```
# import data frame containing a custom timestamp column (ex: _2019_11_19_15_10_35_)
df1 = pd.read_csv('mydatafile.csv').assign(newcol='newval')
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.todatetime(df1['Timestamp'], format='_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_')
```

in something like:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('mydatafile.csv').assign(newcol='newval').todatetime(df1['Timestamp'], format='_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_')
```

I tried also:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('mydatafile.csv').assign(newcol='newval').apply(lambda x: pd.todatetime(df1['Timestamp'], format='_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_') if x.name=='Timestamp' else x)
```

Comment: Hi J, mind if i ask what the end goal of that is? That way we can better help you.

Comment: Hi, sure, I am lazy. I have several datafiles with really specific names ('mydatafile.csv') in a big database so I have to do it manually for all of them, having this done in one line saves me a bit of time. Also and mostly by curiosity on the possiblity of pandas, I want to understand, not use a patchwork of codes I found :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can assign another Timestamp column, erasing the previous one:

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('mydatafile.csv').assign(
    newcol='newval', 
    Timestamp=lambda df: pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick. Only a small typo on to_datetime.